# How to set the Plugins Length to a particular value using playwright/puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, user-agent, playwright

I have been testing my `headless = True` firefox browsers using https://bot.sannysoft.com/ and [playwright stealth](https://pypi.org/project/playwright-stealth/) (a playwright python port of [puppeteer extra stealth](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth)) and have been struggling to increase the plugins length from 3 to 5.
[image: Playwright launched browser]

My normal firefox runs with **5 plugins length** and I think websites are using the plugin count to detect it, as I've fixed everything else to show identically what my normal firefox shows and its only the plugins length that I haven't been able to fix.

Playwright stealth uses this javascript code (see below, copied from the navigator.js file) to set its plugin length (i think), but I've so far been unable to edit it without it breaking and showing a plugin length of 0.

```
data = {
    "mimeTypes": [
        {
            "type": "application/pdf",
            "suffixes": "pdf",
            "description": "",
            "__pluginName": "Chrome PDF Viewer"
        },
        {
            "type": "application/x-google-chrome-pdf",
            "suffixes": "pdf",
            "description": "Portable Document Format",
            "__pluginName": "Chrome PDF Plugin"
        },
        {
            "type": "application/x-nacl",
            "suffixes": "",
            "description": "Native Client Executable",
            "__pluginName": "Native Client"
        },
        {
            "type": "application/x-pnacl",
            "suffixes": "",
            "description": "Portable Native Client Executable",
            "__pluginName": "Native Client"
        }
    ],
    "plugins": [
        {
            "name": "Chrome PDF Plugin",
            "filename": "internal-pdf-viewer",
            "description": "Portable Document Format",
            "__mimeTypes": ["application/x-google-chrome-pdf"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer",
            "filename": "mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai",
            "description": "",
            "__mimeTypes": ["application/pdf"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Native Client",
            "filename": "internal-nacl-plugin",
            "description": "",
            "__mimeTypes": ["application/x-nacl", "application/x-pnacl"]
        }
    ]
}


// That means we're running headful
const hasPlugins = 'plugins' in navigator && navigator.plugins.length
if (!(hasPlugins)) {

    const mimeTypes = generateMagicArray(
        data.mimeTypes,
        MimeTypeArray.prototype,
        MimeType.prototype,
        'type'
    )
    const plugins = generateMagicArray(
        data.plugins,
        PluginArray.prototype,
        Plugin.prototype,
        'name'
    )

    // Plugin and MimeType cross-reference each other, let's do that now
    // Note: We're looping through `data.plugins` here, not the generated `plugins`
    for (const pluginData of data.plugins) {
        pluginData.__mimeTypes.forEach((type, index) => {
            plugins[pluginData.name][index] = mimeTypes[type]
            plugins[type] = mimeTypes[type]
            Object.defineProperty(mimeTypes[type], 'enabledPlugin', {
                value: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(plugins[pluginData.name])),
                writable: false,
                enumerable: false, // Important: `JSON.stringify(navigator.plugins)`
                configurable: false
            })
        })
    }

    const patchNavigator = (name, value) =>
        utils.replaceProperty(Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator), name, {
            get() {
                return value
            }
        })

    patchNavigator('mimeTypes', mimeTypes)
    patchNavigator('plugins', plugins)
}
```

I tried copying over all the plugins that my normal firefox shows on sannysoft (see image below) but that just broke the code and caused it to show as 0 plugins length and fail the Plugins is Type of Array test.
[image: Normal non-playwright plugins]

**Does anyone know how to write this javascript so that the plugins length shows as 5? Even better perhaps an idea on how to write in my exact plugins into the navigator.plugins file? (the above copied javascript)?**

Comment: Can you show the JSON you copied over?